# MySQL error when trying to get unique values using DISTINCT together with LEFT JOIN

Tags: sql, mysql

I have two mysql tables, courses and student_courses, I need to get unique course_names from the course table. But I get a erro when trying to execute my query.

Heres my query

```
        SELECT
            sc.c_id,
            DISTINCT c.course_name
        FROM
            Courses AS c
        LEFT JOIN Student_Courses AS sc ON c.c_id = sc.c_id
        WHERE
            sc.s_id = 4
```

This is the error I get

```
CDbCommand failed to execute the SQL statement: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DISTINCT c.course_name
```

FROM
Courses AS c
LEFT JOIN Student_Courses AS ' at line 3

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`DISTINCT` is a keyword to be used immediately after `SELECT` (Have a look at the [Mysql `SELECT` syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/select.html)). You cannot select columns distinctively, you rather do a `SELECT DISTINCT` query. What you possibly want is a `GROUP BY`. But then you need an [aggregate function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html) (to tell mysql what to do with the other columns - the ones you are not `GROUP`ing `BY`.) Example using [`GROUP_CONCAT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) as aggregate function (Which just concatenates all columns in each group using a comma):

```
SELECT c.course_name, GROUP_CONCAT(sc.c_id),
FROM Courses AS c
LEFT JOIN Student_Courses AS sc ON c.c_id = sc.c_id
WHERE sc.s_id = 4
GROUP BY course_name
```

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT
        DISTINCT sc.c_id,
        c.course_name
FROM
        Courses AS c
LEFT JOIN Student_Courses AS sc ON c.c_id = sc.c_id
WHERE
        sc.s_id = 4
```

the DISTINCT keyword must be the first word after select because it will apply to the whole row.
It's as if you say :

```
SELECT DISTINCT(sc.c_id, c.course_name, ...) FROM ...
```

you can't say :

```
 SELECT sc.c_id, DISTINCT(c.course_name, ...) FROM ...
```